# jmx can't connect to localhost

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, jmx

Trying to connect a simple JMX  monitoring. Managed application and monitoring tool are on the same server. When trying to connect an error

> 00:30:55,610 FATAL http-8080-6 SiteListener:makeJmxConnection:99 - 
>   java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub:
>   javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is
>   java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost;
>   nested exception is:      java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]
>     at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(Unknown Source)
>     at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.m.a.s.SiteListener.makeJmxConnection(SiteListener.java:93)    at
>   com.m.a.s.SiteListener.getMBeanConnect(SiteListener.java:73)  at
>   com.m.a.s.SiteListener.contextInitialized(SiteListener.java:51)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3228)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.reload(ManagerServlet.java:918)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.reload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:545)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doGet(HTMLManagerServlet.java:121)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:558)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is
>   java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost;
>   nested exception is:      java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]
>     at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
>     at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(Unknown Source)
>     ... 26 more Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused
>   to host: localhost; nested exception is:      java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection refused    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)     ... 31 more
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused  at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown
>   Source)   ... 36 more

On the server, open access so

```
 private static void startJmxServer() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        RemouteAuthentificator auth = new RemouteAuthentificator();
        props.put("jmx.remote.authenticator", auth);

        JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:22414/MServer");
        MBeanServer mbeanSrv = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        JMXConnectorServer server = JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(url, props, mbeanSrv);
        server.start();
        log.info("JMX RMI Agent has been bound on address: " + url);
    }
```

In an administrative tool under Tomcat,  trying to connect

```
static private MBeanServerConnection makeJmxConnection(String objectName)
    {
    // objectName = “MServer:name=Settings”;
        MBeanServerConnection mConnect = null;
        try
        {
            String[] credentials = new String[] {"server", "password"};
            Map<String, String[]> props = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
            props.put("jmx.remote.credentials", credentials);

            JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL(“service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:22414/MServer”);
            jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, props);
            mConnect = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
            mbeanName = new ObjectName(objectName);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            log.fatal("", e);
        }

        return mConnect;
    }
```

And tried to connect via external ip. Result is the same.

Comment: would you kindly share you local-host connectivity source code

Answer (score 0):

i don't see where you set your put number.where is you this short of code

```
String host = "localhost";  // or some x.y.z
int port = setyourPortNumber;
String url = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:22414/MServer"; // where you get services
```

i wish it help you to get idea

Comment: Do not quite understand.
First server starts from the first listing. It then starts monitoring tools, from the second listing.

Final url in this and in another case, the variable JMXServiceURL url

Comment: @ferrakkem-bhuiyan Hi, what do you think about https://stackoverflow.com/q/59471539/1410223